# django access context in template

Tags: django, templates, django-queryset, django-context

My code is like this:
I custom my context and want to access my query set in template

```
class GetStudentQueryHandler(ListView):
    template_name = 'client.html'
    paginate_by = STUDENT_PER_PAGE
    context_object_name = 'studentinfo'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(GetStudentQueryHandler, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['can_show_distribute'] = self.request.user.has_perm('can_show_distribute_page')
        context['form'] = QueryStudentForm

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
```

The question is : how to access the queryset returned by the get_queryset method in templates?
I know I can access the custom attributes like studentinfo.can_show_distribute, how to access the query data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it written [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts), the default context variable for `ListView` is `objects_list`

So in template it can be accessed as following:

```
{% for obj in objects_list%}
   {{obj.some_field}}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, it can be set manually with `context_object_name` parameter (as in your example):

```
class GetStudentQueryHandler(ListView):
    # ...
    context_object_name = 'studentinfo'
    # ...
```

and in template:

```
{% for obj in studentinfo %}
   {{obj.some_field}}
{% endfor %}
```

To access the additonally added field `can_show_distribute` from the context in the template:

```
{{ can_show_distribute }}
```

Comment: I know that, but I have customed my context in the get_context_data method, I add fields like 'can_show_distribute', I'm afraid if I use the for loop, I will also access the custom fields, but I just want to display the data returned by the get_queryset method.

Comment: Well, you've done this: `context = super(GetStudentQueryHandler, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`. So your context will include all fields, that `ListView` adds. To access `can_show_distribute` from template you shall do this: `{{can_show_distribute}}`, and not this: `{{studentinfo.can_show_distribute}}`

Comment: so you mean the "studentinfo" object just represent the queryset returned by the get_queryset method? ok I will have a try, if it works I will accept your answer, thank you

Comment: @stalk Do you mean that for different views, the default context variable might differ?

Comment: @tilaprimera by default, *all* instances of `ListView` have variable named [`object_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts). But, you can set specific to current view variable name in `context_object_name` view class property

Comment: Since the accessing of `can_show_distribute` also seemed to be in question, I have proposed to extend the accepted answer accordingly.